# Convert Unicode to UTF-8 byte[] and save into string (Java)

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I need to convert the character unicode to a byte[] representation and save into Srting, for example

```
U+1F601 -> \xF0\x9F\x98\x81
```

I dont have idea how can i do it this..
Anyone has idea?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] codepoints = { 0x1F601 }; // U+1F601
String s = new String(codepoints, 0, codepoints.length);
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // As UTF-8 (Unicode) bytes
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

So one first coposes the Unicode code points into a java String. Java Strings hold Unicode.
When one wants bytes, say in UTF-8 - a Unicode representation -, then one has to indicate the CharSet in which the bytes will be.

Comment: With this code i have [-16, -97, -104, -127] as result..Isnt that i want..no?

Comment: -16 = F0 hex, -97 = 256 - 97 = 159 = 160 - 1 = hex A0 - 1 = 9F. so it is okay.